# How do I combine data from Excel sheet and files in my Google drive in hadoop?

Tags: excel, hadoop

I have the details of students in an Excel sheet and their respective files in my drive. How should I combine the data using Hadoop so that I can analyse and derive results?

Comment: Please post the code which you have already tried. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Excel is not a database, so it cannot be queried directly from Hadoop framework until your file is either on HDFS (ideally as a separate format like Parquet), or you convert it to a proper database instead.

Option 1) Export Excel to a CSV, then upload to Hadoop and proceed from there

Option 2) Use Apache POI (Java) or Pandas (Python) Excel libraries and integrate with Hive on your own, assuming that is what you mean by "Hadoop" here.

Option 3) [Use Spark-Excel](https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel)

---

**Note** unless you have something over 100GB (large random number) of student data, then you'd be better off using MySQL or Postgres instead